# About the use of "of which" phrase

Tags: relative-pronouns

Below is a sentence from a grammar book.

> I have nothing of which to complain.

The book says the phrase "of which" is used as part of a relative pronoun clause.
Suddenly this came confusing to me as I felt I had heard other many similar expressions like that in its shape but with different interpretation of meaning. For example I made up a sentence as follows.

> I have to make a decision of which to choose.

Is also the second sentence right above part of a relative pronoun clause?
Or is it totally different grammatically?

Thank you very much.

Comment: That sounds hypercorrect to me. Most speakers of PDE would say *I have nothing to complain about* or *I have nothing to complain of*.  If we accept the bugbear of not ending the sentence with preposition, we need the relative, **which**. ....about which to complain....of which to complain.

Comment: *Is there something you'd like to talk about?* would become, when obsessively corrected, *Is there something about which you would like to talk?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SHORT VERSION:**

> 1. I have nothing of which to complain.
> 2. I have to make a decision of which to choose.

Two different sorts of relative clause are involved in these sentences.

- In 1, *of which to complain* is a **bound relative clause** modifying *nothing*: *of which* stands for the complement of *complain*.
- In 2, *which to choose* is a **free relative clause** acting as a nominal, the object of the preposition *of*. The preposition phrase ***of*** which to choose is the complement of the noun *decision*; this construction is a standard way of expressing the object of a 'nominalized' transitive verb.

  > *my decision of X* is equivalent to *I decide X*.

  In practice, however, this is pretty stiff and unnatural, because *decide* usually takes a clausal complement rather than a nominal direct object. With *decision* most speakers will omit the *of*:

  > I have to make a decision which to choose.

**LONGER VERSION:**
At one level this is a fairly simple question, involving a contrast between a *bound relative clause* and a *free relative clause*. At another level, however, the question is significantly complicated by the fact that neither sentence is straightforwardly idiomatic: both involve transformations of the underlying expressions.

Let’s start by simplifying: rewriting your two sentences with the infinitivals in the relative clauses recast as ordinary finite verbs. This will make the underlying structures easier to identify (but there will still be lots of complications). Infinitivals like those in your sentences are understood to take the subject of the matrix clause as their own subjects.

> 1. I have nothing of which **to complain**. → I have nothing of which **I complain**, or more idiomatically → I have nothing of which **I can complain**.
> 2. I have to make a decision of which **to choose**.  → I have to make a decision of which **I choose**, or more idiomatically → I have to make a decision of which **I will choose**

(That last sentence in fact is still not particularly natural—I'll come back to that later.)

Let’s now look first at the ‘cores’ of those two relative clauses, the pieces I’ve put in boldface, and see how they work. A relativizer—a *wh-* word or *that*—points rightward to a missing element, a ‘trace’ or ‘gap’ which must be supplied from context, like the blank in a fill-in-the-blank question. In effect, the relativizer is a ‘variable’, so let’s represent it as ***X***

- In sentence 1, the verb *complain* takes a preposition phrase with *of* (or *about*) as its complement. Both  ***X***  **and** the preposition *of* are needed to make a meaningful English clause:

  > ☒ I can complain ***X***
  >   ☑ I can complain **of** ***X***.

  Note that in this case the preposition *of* might have been left ‘stranded’ at the end of the relative clause:

  > I have nothing which I can complain of.

  In sentence 1, then, *of* is part of the relative clause.
- In sentence 2, however, *of* is **not** part of the relative clause. The verb *choose* takes a noun phrase as its object but does **not** take a preposition phrase headed by *of* as its complement<sup>†</sup>, so we can’t put the *of* inside it:

  > ☑ I will choose ***X***.
  >   ☒ I will choose of ***X***.

  <sup>†</sup> <sup>Just to make things more complicated, *choose* **can** take a preposition phrase headed by *between* or *among* as its complement; but that’s not relevant here.</sup>

  In sentence 2, then, *of* is **not** part of the relative clause.

  *... Then where does it come from?* Of *with a nominalized transitive verb—in your example,* decision < decide—*in many cases introduces the object of the underlying verb:*

  > I define X as Y → my definition **of** X as Y

  *And that's really the only way you can parse* a decision of which to choose: which to choose *is the object of* decide *and thus the 'oblique' object of* decision. *But as explained in the 'Short Version' this is not a very natural way of expressing that thought*

All this at last brings us around to the 'simple' part of the question. Relative clauses have two very different uses, 'bound' and 'free':

- In sentence 1, *of which to complain* is a 'bound relative clause'. It is 'bound' to the word *nothing*<sup>‡</sup>—that is, *which* points backward to *nothing* in the matrix clause and 'modifies' it. As a modifier the relative clause would be described in tradtional terms as *adjectival*.

  <sup>‡</sup> <sup>If you want to get *really* technical, it's actually bound to *thing*—syntactically the 'words' *nothing*, *something*, *anything*, *everything* are determinate noun phrases, D+NP, and following modifiers are taken to lie in the NP piece modifying the head *thing*: [<sub>D</sub>no <sub>NP</sub>[thing of which to complain]].</sup>
- In sentence 2, *which to choose* is a 'free relative clause*. It isn't 'bound' to a particular entity in the matrix clause but acts independently as the object of the preposition *of*. As object of a preposition the relative clause would be described in traditional terms as *nominal*.